# How to install EGit plugin in Eclipse manually

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit

I have a crazy situation, my company restricted my main desktop's access to internet due to some security constraints. So there is only one solution left to integrate Git (through **EGit**) manually into eclipse.

But I could not find any article or post on this. Could you please help me to integrate Git into Eclipse without *Help* > *Install New Software...*

Comment: egit already ships as part of eclipse, no additional software installation is required (since [kepler](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/06/26/top-10-eclipse-kepler-features/)).

Comment: You may want to reconsider your engagement with a company that gets in your way regarding your daily work for 'security reasons'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a variety of *Eclipse Packages* that cone with a pre-arranged set of plug-ins.

The main page that lists all available packages is here: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

Most of them (if not all) contain the *Git integration for Eclipse* aka EGit. Follow the links to the detail pages to see which plug-ins are contained.

As described in [@nitind's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27905/nitind) answer, if really necessary, the EGit repository as a whole can be downloaded in a zipped archive here: https://eclipse.org/egit/download. After downloading, go to *Help* > *Install New Software...* and select the *Add...* button to register a local software repository. Thereafter you can select the desired EGit components as usual.

Answer (score 2):

You can always try downloading the “EGit p2 repository ZIP download for system integrators“, which is an archive of egit’s own Update Site for a particular release.